# Multiple steps for spotless format java error while gradle build

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

There is an IntelliJ project using Gradle, Java and in one of the modules, I put the Java code which is working independently. But on moving the code within this project and running the build.gradle I am getting the following error:

> Could not create task ':wlcr-auto-api:spotlessJavaApply'. Could not
> create task ':wlcr-auto-api:spotlessJava'. Multiple steps with name
> 'google-java-format' for spotless format 'java'

I am not sure what is the reason for this error. Also, I am not sure if the project structure is correct in Intellij.

[image]

In the above image **auto** is the project that was already created. I created a new module **auto-api** and put all my code inside it. There is an Application.java inside it, the main file to run the spring boot application. It works when the code is not put inside this **auto** project. But not when included in the project.
I have no clue how to debug this.

Comment: This error disappears if I comment out a `plugin id: com.internal....` But this custom plugin is required for other things. Not sure if we could just stop spotless from including or running

Answer (score 0):

check out your build.gradle - probably you missed something inside block:

```
spotless {
    ...
}
```

at least, if you simply remove it - the issue will gone

Comment: I searched in the entire codebase the term `spotless` doesn't appear

Comment: This error disappears if I comment out a `plugin id: com.internal....` But this custom plugin is required for other things. Not sure if we could just stop spotless from including or running